# Trouble accessing a dynamically generated javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, http, flask, bokeh

I am creating a plotting application with Python's `bokeh`.

`bokeh` dynamically generates javascript used in its plotting visualizations.

My setup works when I am running the debug server from within my IDE, but I get the following error when I attempt to run the app on a server and access it from a browser:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5006/bokeh/jsgenerate/VBox/PlottingApp/PlottingApp net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

If I put the following into the terminal, I get all the javascript fine.

`$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5006/bokeh/jsgenerate/VBox/PlottingApp/PlottingApp`

Where is this access problem originating from? I am using `Flask` as my application framework, `uwsgi` as my app server, and `nginx` as my webserver. Let me know if there are configuration settings within these modules that you need to see.

Answer (score 1):

Remote ajax calls are denied by default. Make sure your server returns this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```